# Is it correct to say you are talking “to Skype”?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Let's say you receive a message from someone but cannot talk to them because you are on a Skype call.

Which is the correct preposition to use for saying that you are busy using Skype?

"Sorry, I am talking ***to*** Skype at the moment"? or "talking ***at*** Skype"?

Also, "talking via Skype" sounds a bit too formal to me.

What would be the common way for saying this?

Comment: What's wrong with *talking on Skype*? (Cf. your sentence 'because you are on a Skype call.')

Comment: @Void Did you see me ruling it out anywhere?

Comment: No, but I'm saying that the preposition in your first sentence (...because you are **on** a Skype call) is correct

Comment: Just as you don't talk ***to*** the telephone, you wouldn't normally ***talk to Skype.*** But given the question says *because you are on a Skype call,* why would you not just say *Sorry, I am **on a Skype call / on Skype** at the moment*.

Comment: Because I was looking for a shorter way to say it. "I am on a Skype call" is a bit too long. "I am on Skype"  though sounds good.

Comment: From what I understand from the responses, *at* was ruled out as well.

Comment: "Talking at [someone]" is a way to describe someone talking to someone else without actually caring about or listening to what the other person is saying. That wouldn't apply here and that's really the only context where "talk at" would be grammatical.

Comment: Does it really matter that you're using Skype to make the call? Just say you're on a call.

Comment: Why even mention the method of communicating?  "I'm on a call". Would you say "I'm on a WhatsApp call", "I'm on a Zoom call", "I'm on a telephone call"?  Mentioning the product is, to me, the same as signing off your emails with "Created with my iPhone", it's just free marketing for the product and probably some attempted kudos.

Comment: If you really feel a need to mention Skype, treat it as grammatically equivalent to the telephone.

Comment: @Kat and @@Neil, sure, but the purpose of the question was to find the correct way to mention Skype. The answer to a problem is not to remove the problem itself. And to take it further, yes, it does make a difference if I use skype, because it implies different behaviour/engagement etc. From a usage perspective, the telephone is not equal to Skype.

Comment: Imagine that you are using Skype. While using Skype, your cellphone rings. If that happens, press the power button, or down volume button to make your phone stop ringing. There is no reason to tell the person not on Skype that you are not available. The non-Skype will know that you are not available when after they hear your answering machine (voicemail prompt)

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon again, and to all similar-minded people here, if you don't see any point in the question, you can just leave the thread. This is an English Learners corner.

Comment: @Sebiti our point is that english speakers typically wouldn't specify the name of the software they're using to make the call, they would simply say they're on a call. You say "on a Skype call" is too long, but you want to remove the most important word and keep an irrelevant one. "I'm on Skype" doesn't convey the message you want (Skype has text chat too), and "I'm talking on Skype" is more awkward, less clear, and equally long as "I'm on a Skype call",  so I'm not sure why the accepted answer satisfies you better than "I'm on a call".

Comment: @Kat actually the answer I've chosen specifically mentions "talking". I understand your point, but I think it is a matter of preference. Especially when in my question no specific context has been given. I waited a bit to choose the answer, maybe I will find a more fitting answer in the future, but I have checked all comments and answers, and I think opinions converged on Colin Fine's.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would say *talking **on** Skype*.

"Talking to Skype" means that you are talking to Skype the company.

Comment: Even though this answer is perfectly fine, and I'm not sure if this is just me, I would personally say "I'm on a skype call" if I was in the OP's described situation.

Comment: I might also say I'm "talking to Skype" if I'm literally speaking at the software, which happens a lot when it's being slow/buggy. "Come on, dude, just let me open the settings dialogue..."

Comment: This is also by analogy with other means of vocal communication.  You don't talk *to* the phone, you talk *on* the phone.

Answer (score 10):

"Sorry, I am Skyping at the moment"

If you search it you will see that such usage is quite common, eg https://www.zdnet.com/google-amp/article/why-are-we-all-zooming-and-not-skyping/

Comment: Oddly, no one says they're "zooming" or "twittering". But sending a text message is "texting". The rule seems to be "add an ING to the end, but only if the result can't be confused with a real word".

Comment: @OwenReynolds they’re not that common, but ‘zooming’ or ‘twittering’ would probably both be understandable in context.

Comment: @OwenReynolds My family and I have definitely used "zooming" e.g. are you zooming tonight? (my dad asking if I'm talking to my friends on a Friday night which I normally do). Also for twittering, you'd either use tweeting if you were tweeting, or DMing if you were suing twitter DMs and these are both in common usage.

Comment: @OwenReynolds It's only not "twittering" because the bird logo induces a specific word for that -- "tweeting" :-)

Comment: @OwenReynolds I say "tweeting", because the action is a "tweet", but to my surprise, [some dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/twittering) claim you *can* say "twittering" when you mean "sending tweets".

Comment: @Fivesideddice You're agreeing with me, right? Zooming is only fine in context, otherwise it's ambiguous: "my kids are zooming away at their homework" could mean they're doing it very fast.

Comment: @ChrisDown Sure. But it was "twittering" and "twits" at first, which the creators felt were weird (I assume since those are also real words that can be applied to humans). "Tweeting" came later and fixed the problem (unless we get human-bird hybrids, who frequently for-real tweet).

Comment: @OwenReynolds well sure but things being potentially ambiguous without context is a pretty common thing in english.  zooming is pretty well established, to the point where it's primary usage is about zoom the product rather than 'to go fast' unless it's something obvious like 'the car went zooming away'.  in the internet age, how a word is commonly used can change incredibly quickly.

Comment: @eps But I can tell you I'm Skyping away in my car, or joke that my cat is Skyping with no ambiguity. I can tell my grandmother I'm Skyping and she may may not know it, but won't misinterpret. Skping is safe since it wasn't a word before.

Comment: @OwenReynolds ok now do twitter and tweeting. these words are centuries (millennia?) old and yet they are now nearly exclusively used to talk about the webservice. `The rule seems to be "add an ING to the end, but only if the result can't be confused with a real word"` well this is obviously not the case since my link says: `Once upon a time, people Skyped. Now they are Zooming. What happened?` and `Zooming is now all the rage.` I highly doubt the author would use that term if it wasn't something that would be commonly understood.

Comment: @eps: There is no ambiguity in `Once upon a time, people Skyped. Now they are Zooming.` because of the association created by parallel construction.  `Zooming is now all the rage.` is a problem because its meaning is ambiguous outside of context.

Comment: @eps Tbe article is also from last March, when Zoom was newish. It starts light. They joke about the awkeard wording: "Zoom is, well, zooming". The title is humorous, as in "we all know using Skype is Skyping, so I guess using Zoom is Zooming?"

Answer (score 8):

When you are talking on the phone, you are *on* a call or *on* the phone. This is true both for landlines and for mobile phones, and this usage has been established for decades or at this point, a century.

Thus, its natural to extend this to VoIP and other teleconferencing solutions, like Skype. You are *on* a call, *on* a *Skype* call or simply *on Skype*. All of these would sound natural.

Talking "to" Skype sounds unnatural, unless you were talking with their customer support, but even then, it would be more appropriate to say that you are talking "*with* someone from Skype".

If you say "talking *to*", you specify the *target*, e.g. "I was talking to Bob about this". But You aren't really talking *to* Skype, you are only *using* it to talk *to* another person.

You might say that you are talking *via* Skype, but that is more rare. "I was talking to Bob via Skype" would be possible, but *on* is also perfectly natural here and I'd argue more common.

Note that you can also say "I'm *in* a Skype call", especially if you are in a call with more than one other person. This stems from the usage of being *in* a conference or meeting, and has since extended to Skype calls with multiple people (or other software, for that matter).

Answer (score 4):

You can talk to Skype if Skype refers to a Skype bot (an autonomous program that can help you test your connection and configuration) or a Skype assistant (a person who works at Skype and supports you). Skype could be a person’s (quite peculiar) name.

Otherwise, you talk on Skype.

Answer (score 3):

Some examples of English phrases are given below:

| Phrase | Good or Bad |
| --- | --- |
| "I am talking ***to*** Skype at the moment" | ***Bad*** |
| "I am talking ***at*** Skype at the moment" | ***Bad*** |
| "I am talking to someone ***via*** Skype at the moment" | Good |
| "I am talking ***on*** Skype with someone else right now, and can't talk" | Good |
| "Sorry, I am ***on a Skype call*** with someone else right now" | Good |
| "Sorry, I am using Skype right now. I will to call you back later" | Good |
| "I am sorry, but I am actually in the middle of talking to someone else right now. Can I call you back later?" | Good |
| "I am using my computer to video chat with someone else right at this moment; I will have to call you back." | Good |
| "I am in the middle of a Skype call" | Good |
| "I am using my computer to video chat with someone right now. I am sorry, but I have to call you back later." | Good |
| "I can't talk right now. Can I call you back later?" | Good |

Many many sentences in English can be understood by drawing two dots connected by an arrow.

[image: TWO DOTS CONNECTED MY ARROWS]

For example, the sentence,

> "Joe gave a bicycle to his daughter Sarah."

[image: DIAGRAM OF JOE GIVING BICYCLE TO SARAH]

Consider the sentence,

> "I am talking at Skype" (this is ***bad*** English)

[image: PICTURE OF JOE TALKING TO SKYPE]

The sentence "I am  talking ***to*** Skype at the moment" is ***wrong*** for the same reason that all of the following are wrong:

- The man was talking to the brick wall.
- The woman was talking to her cup of tea.
- The child was talking to their toy car.
- Sarah was talking to the cardboard box.
- Ian was speaking to the telephone pole.
- I am talking to my bedspread.

Skype is a computer program.
Talking to non-living things is strange.
Talking to Skype would be a strange thing to do.

Both of the following are correct:

> "I am talking to someone else, via skype"
> "I am talking, via skype, to someone else"

The word "*I* " is like a dot (a source)
The phrase "*am talking via skype to*" is like an arrow.
The phrase "*someone else*" is like a destination dot.

*Skype* is like a plastic water bottle.
You don't drink a water bottle.
If you drank a water bottle, plastic would be inside of your stomach.
Likewise, you can talk to someone, but you cannot talk to Skype.

There is an English aphorism which states:

> "Life is all about the journey, not the destination."

The destination of life is death. Thus, one is supposed to enjoy the journey.

Anyway, Skype is more like a Journey than a destination.

More examples of English are shown below:

| ***BAD*** English | ***GOOD*** English | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "I drove ***to*** my car." | "I drove to Delhi in my Uncle's Car" | The car is like an arrow in my diagrams. The car is not a dot or circle. |
| "I drove ***at*** my car." | "I used my car to drive to Mumbai" | The Car is used on the journey. The Car is not the destination. |
| "I ate my spoon" (*BAD*) | "I used a spoon to eat my Daal-Palak Ka Shorba" | In one case, your stomach now contains a steel, or wood, spoon. |
| I talked to Skype | I used Skype to talk to my sister | You can not talk to Skype, Skype is a computer program |

Comment: Could you clarify why is "at" wrong as well? Is it because it implies a location maybe? (Thanks for the elaborate answer btw).

Comment: @Sebiti I have edited the post to explain why the sentence "I am talking ***AT*** Skype" is also incorrect. I don't know if you have seen and old-fashion magnetic compass before; the kind of compass which always points North. The word "*at*" in English is like the needle on a Compass. The word "at" shows which way a person is facing or talking. "I was talking at my sister" or "I was talking at my mother." Technically, "speaking to" is better English than "talking at." We would say "I was speaking to my sister" instead of "I was talking at my sister."

Comment: @Sebiti You are not allowed to use "talk to" or "talk at" unless you say ***who*** you were talking to. Good English is, "I was talking to my sister." If you do not want to say who, then you say, "I am talking to somebody." The sentence "I was talking to the telephone" is also wrong. The word "talk" is usually used to ignore the technology/electronics involved. You can talk to your sister using the phone. You can talk to your sister via telephone. You cannot talk to a telephone. If you do talk to a telephone, it is like talking to a brick wall, or talking to a rock.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the Skype part is not actually relevant and can be dropped, given that you concern is that the phrase is too long. The person you are talking to is unlikely to care whether you are busy talking on Skype, Teams, Zoom or a phone call. The salient point is that you are unavailable to them.

So I'd say "I'm on a call"

Answer (score 1):

*I'm talking **on** Skype*

or

*I'm talking **through** Skype*

or

*I'm talking **to** someone **on/through** Skype*

You could also say *I'm in a Skype call*.

"To Skype" implies you're talking to Skype itself, which would be appropriate if, for example, Skype had voice control you were using and someone in the other room thought you were talking to them. In that situation, it'd be appropriate to say

*Sorry, I was just talking **to** Skype*

Comment: Got it. 
So "I am *on* a Skype call" is wrong as well? Or are in/on both correct?

Comment: "I am on a Skype call" is also correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use "I'm talking through Skype" without also adding "to [someone]" (or using e.g. "We" or "[Someone] and I" instead of "I"). Using "through" emphasises there being someone on the other end and raises the question of whom.

Comment: "*on* a call" sounds odd to me, but it might be a dialectal difference.

Comment: @mathrick In which _dialect_ would "_on_ a call" sound odd?